# Gmail addon forward multiple messages without using filter

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

in my company environment auto-forward vial gmail filter has been deactivated by admin for security reasons. However I am in the situation of having to forward multiple emails on a daily basis. So I thought I program a little addon that can help me.

The workflow should be:

1. select multiple emails in the main window (manually)
2. open widget / add-on in the sidebar
3. enter email addresses to forward to
4. press send

While I am able to create a widget in the sidebar via CardService. I struggle to "grab" the selected emailthreads in an array or List, so I can loop and forward.

My question: After pressing "send" I need to grab the selected mails via AppScript code, like

```
var selectedMail = [email1, email2, ...]
```

Could anyone please help me to kickstart this? Thanks!

Comment: You have to open one email to get the gmail addon so I guess you will have forward them one and a time.  I'd probably just launch a dialog that reads your inbox and allows you to select all of them that you want and then run one function to forward them all. [GmailMessage.forward](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String)) [GmailApp.getInboxThreads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getInboxThreads(Integer,Integer))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

It's currently not possible to access selected threads in Gmail add-on.

#### Feature request:

This feature has already been requested in Issue Tracker:

- [Ability to access selected email threads from Addon](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/132655505)

I'd suggest you to [star the referenced issue](https://developers.google.com/issue-tracker/guides/subscribe#subscribing_by_starring_an_issue) in order to help prioritizing it and to keep track of it.

#### Workaround:

With current functionalities, I think your best option (as mentioned by [Cooper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70798075/gmail-addon-forward-multiple-messages-without-using-filter#comment125160372_70798075)) would be to:

- Retrieve all threads in your inbox (see [getInboxThreads](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#getinboxthreads)), either to a custom HTML ([web apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), [dialogs and sidebars](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs)) or to an add-on [Card](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/add-ons/concepts/card-interfaces).
- Select your desired threads on that custom HTML/Card (using checkboxes, or what have you - see [SelectionInput](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/card-service/selection-input) for cards).
- Once your desired threads are selected, call a function that will forward the corresponding messages, using [GmailMessage.forward](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#forward(String,Object)).

Comment: Thanks for your time and posting all the links! This is helping me a lot!

Comment: @lamblichus  done